# Jquery .on('click,'button' not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if user closed browser. There is no reliable way, but the most accurate way seems to use `onbeforeunload` and check if a link or a button was clicked. I will also add f5 and some other extra checking.

But I have problem with button. If I click button, ajax call will be made even if there is `if(window.link_was_clicked==false)` condition.

```
<button onclick="setLocation('http://dev.site.com/checkout/')" class="button" title="Checkout" type="button"><span><span>Checkout</span></span></button>
```

And script:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'button', function(event) {
  window.link_was_clicked= true;
});  

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if(window.link_was_clicked==false){                
    //make ajax call      
  }
};
```

It seems the problem is because there is setLocation function attached to button `onclick`. Is there any way to trigger `jQuery(document).on` first?

Comment: which button are you talking about? are you talking about the browser close button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277403/how-to-detect-if-a-link-was-clicked-when-window-onbeforeunload-is-triggered

Comment: Where is your HTML? If you aren't using a `<button>` tag then your jQuery won't select anything.

Comment: Your HTML is too sparse.

Comment: @Sushil I am talking about <button> html tag. I put now this into question.

Comment: Why not put your onclick code inside of your jQuery click handler, so it gets called in the same place and you have neater code?

Comment: the only way i can see to make it work is by adding the onclick to the button in the old fashioned way (i wouldn't recommend though),

`var btn = jQuery('button'); btn[0] && btn[0].onclick = function () {window.link_was_clicked = true; setLocation('http://dev.site.com/checkout/');};`

something like this

Comment: try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chhetrisushil/RM33L/)

Answer (score 0):

That variable doesnt exist on before load. so add it on the top and try again

```
     window.link_was_clicked=window.link_was_clicked||false;
     jQuery(document).on('click', 'button', function(event) {
         window.link_was_clicked= true;
      });  

     window.onbeforeunload = function() {
         if(window.link_was_clicked==false){                
        //make ajax call      
     }
    };
```

Comment: In real code it is `window.link_was_clicked= false;`, I just wanted to keep example short and easy. So this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided the code for `setLocation()`, I'll assume that that's where the problem is. Now, regarding a change to the order of execution of your click event handlers:

It is in general bad to have both embedded `onclick` and jquery-bound handlers, it leads to all sorts of confusion. If you can't change the html, however, you could do what this guy suggests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7507888/2685386

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myClick = $('button').attr('onclick');
    $('button').removeAttr('onclick');

    $(document).on('click', 'button', function(e) {
        window.link_was_clicked=true;
        // do my other stuff here....
        eval(myClick);// this will now call setLocation()
    });
});
```